# How i send socket.io android to nodejs to client html

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

I want to send data via socket io from android to nodejs as backend. After that the data from node js backend sent to client html js socket io.

however I am having difficulty in receiving data inside io client socket in html

This Is My Code In Android studio

```
ImageButton Buttun = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.emergency_button);
        Buttun.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    json.putOpt("emergency", "true");
                    json.putOpt("lat_cor", "dfefehjefj");
                    json.putOpt("long_cor", "fejfejfe");
                    mSocket.emit("broadcaster", json);
                    Toast.makeText(EmergencyButton.this, json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

then I send it to the websocket that I run using js node

this Is My Code In Node JS Server Socket.io

```
WebSocket.sockets.on('connection', function (io) {
    /** Aksi Yang Akan Terjadi Jika Web Socket Menerima Koneksi Dari User Yang Connect Di Dalam System Database **/
    /** ############################### AWAL FUNGSI REGISTER PADA MEMBER USER ############################## **/
    io.emit('broadcaster_emergency', {"dsd": true, "sdfse": false});
    io.on('broadcaster', function (callback) {
        io.emit('broadcaster_emergency', {"dsd": true, "sdfse": false});
        console.log(callback);

    });

    /** Fungsi Untuk Melakukan Pengecekan Jika Ada User Yang Keluar/Menutup Tab Sesi Yang Sedang Berlangsung : */
    io.on('disconnect', function () {
        Winston.info('Client Tidak Aktif');
    });
    /** Akhir Fungsi Untuk Melakukan Pengecekan Jika Ada User Yang Keluar/Menutup Tab Sesi Yang Sedang Berlangsung : */

});
```

After that the client server must receive data from nodejs with javascript native socket.io

This Is My Code Javascript Client Web

```
var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:8081');
        socket.on("broadcaster_emergency", function (data) {
            addMarker({lat: -5.111929, lng: 119.4190643}, 'Pasar');
            //socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
        });
```

but data sent from android is only sent in js node and appears in the command prompt.

but data in my browser does not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your socket server, emits data back to sender(back to Android client in your case), not to the rest of connected clients. So, your browser client, it is not going to be notified.

If you want to emit the received data on `broadcaster` to all connected clients except the sender, you should do as follows:

```
// sending to all clients except sender
io.broadcast.emit('broadcaster_emergency', {"dsd": true, "sdfse": false});
```

If you want to know how to emit events for other specific situations, check [this](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/#).